# Pass argument to mysql script from mysql client

Tags: mysql, command-line, arguments

Is there a way/workaround/hack to pass an argument to a mysql script?
Let's say I have a file name myqueries.sql which looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM FooBar where id = <arg>;
```

Then in mysql command, I know I can call this script by

```
mysql>source myqueries.sql
```

But is there a way to pass an argument here? Something like this:

```
mysql>source myqueries.sql 2
```

then I'd get the tuple with id = 2.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9908609) seems to be a workaround.

Comment: I've looked at that before, but it wouldn't work in my case since I can't launch mysql myself. let's say once I exit mysql, i can't go back.

Comment: Are you on win or nix?

Comment: Unix, but I don't think it matters what OS I'm on, right?

Answer (score 1):

myqueries.sql

```
SELECT * FROM FooBar where id = @arg;
```

on mysql

```
set @arg=2;
source myqueries.sql
```